# Excel formula to cut characters to certain amount if more than value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have sentence in `AK30` where character limit should be 45. How to set it with formula so that if there are more than 45 characters in `AK30` cut needed amount of characters from the right?

I have tried with but can't get the logic for `LEFT(AK30;LEN(AK30)-10)` to work correct:

```
=IF(LEN(AK30)>45;LEFT(AK30;LEN(AK30)-10);AK30)
```

Comment: Isn't it just `=IF(LEN(AK30)>45;LEFT(AK30,45);ak30)` ?

Comment: You can just do `LEFT(A1, 45)`. If the cell is not longer then it will just return the same cell value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `=LEFT(AK30; 45)`

If your string is less than 45 characters that will just return the same value. It will only actually change the string when the LEN exceeds 45